# Отправить значение из функции в api

Tags: javascript, php, html, json, api

Я создаю магазин на CMS системе. Там есть API. У меня стоит такая задача:Клиент вводит число (вес продукта),  после меняется цена , в зависимости от того, что написал клиент. Цена должна меняться не просто визуально, а отправляться в корзину, чекаут и в админку. Есть

```
APISingleProductAddEdit:
      type: object
      properties:
        sku:
          type: string
          example: "dkasj234"
          description: The SKU od the product
        model:
          type: string
        minimum:
          type: integer
          description: minimum items to add to cart
          example: 10
        upc:
          type: string
          description: UPC code for current product
        weight:
          type: integer
          format: float
          description: Numeric value of the weight of the product, if not passed it is zero
          example: 40
        weight_class_id:
          type: integer
          format: int32
          description: The id of the weight class you are using for current product (There is separate API request that return all the weight classes, check "misc/dimension_lst")
          example: 3
        length:
          type: integer
          format: float
          description: Numeric value of the length of the product, if not passed it is zero
          example: 15
        width:
          type: integer
          format: float
          description: Numeric value of the width of the product, if not passed it is zero
          example: 15
        height:
          type: integer
          format: float
          description: Numeric value of the height of the product, if not passed it is zero
          example: 15
        length_class_id:
          type: integer
          format: int32
          description: The id of the length class you are using for current product (There is separate API request that return all the weight classes, check "misc/dimension_lst")
          example: 3
        stock_status:
          type: integer
          description: Valid stock status id (you can find them in separate API call the returns stock status ids)
          example: 7
        subtract:
          type: integer
          format: boolean
          description: Pass '1' if you want to activate subtruct feature, if not pass '0'
        sort_order:
          type: integer
          description: The order of the product related to another products
          example: 9
        status:
          type: integer
          format: boolean
          description: If you want disactivate the product pass '0' else pass '1'
        keyword:
          type: string
          description: Keyword related to SEO
          example: food
        quantity:
          type: integer
          description: The quantity of your product
          example: 10
        hidden:
          type: integer
          format: boolean
          example: 0
          description: Hide your product from the customers by passing '1' else pass '0'
        image:
          type: string
          description: Valid URL for valid image format (jpg,jpeg,png)
        images:
          type: array
          items:
            type: object
            properties:
              image:
                type: string
                description: Valid image url with valid image types same as the main image
              sort_order:
                type: integer
                format: int64
                description: The order of the curront image related to another images for this product
        price:
          type: number
          format: float
          example: 56.76
        product_related:
          type: array
          items:
            type: integer
            description: Each element in this array is product id that will be related to current product
          example: [12,15,33]
        product_category:
          type: array
          items:
            type: integer
            description: Each element in this array is category id that will be related to current product
          example: [555,444,123]
        product_description:
          $ref: '#/components/schemas/ProductLanguageObject'` APISingleProductAddEdit:
      type: object
      properties:
        sku:
          type: string
          example: "dkasj234"
          description: The SKU od the product
        model:
          type: string
        minimum:
          type: integer
          description: minimum items to add to cart
          example: 10
        upc:
          type: string
          description: UPC code for current product
        weight:
          type: integer
          format: float
          description: Numeric value of the weight of the product, if not passed it is zero
          example: 40
        weight_class_id:
          type: integer
          format: int32
          description: The id of the weight class you are using for current product (There is separate API request that return all the weight classes, check "misc/dimension_lst")
          example: 3
        length:
          type: integer
          format: float
          description: Numeric value of the length of the product, if not passed it is zero
          example: 15
        width:
          type: integer
          format: float
          description: Numeric value of the width of the product, if not passed it is zero
          example: 15
        height:
          type: integer
          format: float
          description: Numeric value of the height of the product, if not passed it is zero
          example: 15
        length_class_id:
          type: integer
          format: int32
          description: The id of the length class you are using for current product (There is separate API request that return all the weight classes, check "misc/dimension_lst")
          example: 3
        stock_status:
          type: integer
          description: Valid stock status id (you can find them in separate API call the returns stock status ids)
          example: 7
        subtract:
          type: integer
          format: boolean
          description: Pass '1' if you want to activate subtruct feature, if not pass '0'
        sort_order:
          type: integer
          description: The order of the product related to another products
          example: 9
        status:
          type: integer
          format: boolean
          description: If you want disactivate the product pass '0' else pass '1'
        keyword:
          type: string
          description: Keyword related to SEO
          example: food
        quantity:
          type: integer
          description: The quantity of your product
          example: 10
        hidden:
          type: integer
          format: boolean
          example: 0
          description: Hide your product from the customers by passing '1' else pass '0'
        image:
          type: string
          description: Valid URL for valid image format (jpg,jpeg,png)
        images:
          type: array
          items:
            type: object
            properties:
              image:
                type: string
                description: Valid image url with valid image types same as the main image
              sort_order:
                type: integer
                format: int64
                description: The order of the curront image related to another images for this product
        price:
          type: number
          format: float
          example: 56.76
        product_related:
          type: array
          items:
            type: integer
            description: Each element in this array is product id that will be related to current product
          example: [12,15,33]
        product_category:
          type: array
          items:
            type: integer
            description: Each element in this array is category id that will be related to current product
          example: [555,444,123]
        product_description:
          $ref: '#/components/schemas/ProductLanguageObject'
```

Вставил тот код из API , как мне  мне кажется, который относится к моей задаче. Как я думаю её выполнить. Я создаю форму, в которую клиент пишет цифры, функция их считывает и отправляет значение в 
 `price:          type: number           format: float           example: 56.76`
В общем вопрос следующий, как вообще отправить данные в API ? Что хотя бы для этого нужно делать? Можно какой-то пример ?

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Что за CMS? Если есть API, может в таком случае есть и документация к нему?

Comment: А что это за формат такой или какой язык? У Вас теги стоят но это не js, json, html, php а что то другое.  Никто не знает как у Вас написана API укажите хотя бы какая CMS стоит. Отправлять и получать нужно согласно документации к вашей CMS и API

Comment: @Simon CMS - Sellavi.  К сожалению документации нет, голая API

Comment: @Greg-- вот просто ссылка на API https://app.swaggerhub.com/apis/sellavi-com/sellavi-ru/1.0.6#/SingleProductAddEdit

Comment: То что вы указали и есть API, там расписано как обращаться (GET, PUT, POST, DELETE) а какие еще вам нужны запросы? А правее даже примеры есть в виде json

Comment: @Greg-- Я хочу понять, как в принципе отправляются данные из JS в бэк. Я так понимаю, что это нужно сделать при помощи API. Я её нашел. Я напишу функцию расчета, создам форму для ввода данных, но не могу понять как мне отправить их.

Comment: Отправляете на `https://ru.sellavi.com/gateway` в вашей ссылке выше так написано  запрос через ajax и обрабатываете через js результат Например введите в браузере (получить продукт с id 2)  `https://ru.sellavi.com/gateway/products/2` увидите ошибку так как нужно сгенерировать token, когда сгенерируете token будет ответ в виде json но это не лучший пример

Comment: Если вы нажмете в правой колонке `Authorize` и зададите пароль любой то при нажатии на `try it out` увидите данные в формате котором будет вам отдавать ваш сайт. Как по мне более правильный метод делать запрос - js AJAX - запрос в php и уже php обращается по API к CMS. Но я фронт а не бэк разработчик, могу ошибаться